# select versions from only one type in paper_trail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin, ruby-2.1, paper-trail-gem

I want to select only the versions from papertrail where the type is "user". Is there any way to get the 5 latest changes for the type User ?

Now i have it like below, but this gives me the 5 latest of all types.

```
table_for PaperTrail::Version.order('id desc').limit(5) do 
// some code for what to do
end
```

Comment: So i fixed it myself. This was all i had to do.

Answer (score 0):

So i fixed it myself. This was all i had to do.

```
table_for PaperTrail::Version.order('id desc').where("item_type = ?", "user").limit(5) do
//some code
end
```